# Who is the first human to be assimilated by the Borg?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, borg

Was the family of seven of nine the first humans to be assimilated in the 2350s? Was it because of them that the Borg first learnt about humanity?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Chronologically, no. The first humans assimilated by Borg were crew members of Picard's Enterprise-E on  **April 5, 2063** ("Star Trek: First Contact"); after the Borg jumped back in time to prevent First Contact between Vulcans and Humans as a result of Cochrane's first Warp flight, and Enterprise followed the Borg Sphere to prevent that.

Next incident was from the same time discrepancy - in **2153**, the remains of Borg Sphere that Enterprise destroyed were found and thawed out Borg assimilated the research team

The next one was **2356** assimilation of the *Raven*, with Hansen family aboard.

More details on Memory Alpha: http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Human-Borg_history

Comment: Time travel. It gives me a headache... :P

Comment: I agree. A headache indeed. Logically without this time travel. It seems that the Hansens were the first human victims.

Comment: Except technically the out-o- canon writings indicate the first Borg were HUMANS. This implies non-canonically, of course,  Star Trek: Destiny, Book 3 Lost Souls, where one Caeliar merged with two Humans to form the first Borg, and the Kindir were the first species assimilated after that. Curse you writers!

Answer (score 0):

Time travel shenanigans aside, I don't think the Hansen's were the first humans assimilated by the Borg. It's implied in 'Dark Frontier' that the Borg were already active in and around the Romulan Neutral Zone in 2353 and therefore venturing close to Federation territory. No doubt there were a number of Federation ships that disappeared without a trace who were victims of the Borg and might have been why the Federation science council approved the expedition in the first place. We know from 'Infinite regress' that the Starship Tombaugh was assimilated in 2362, so in all likelihood Federation ships were falling prey to the Borg for some years.

Comment: In a world where time travel is a regular thing, you can't put it aside.